# How do I use text link in jQuery while preserving clicks that open to new tabs/windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently made a link that I attach the "click" event to ajax some content.  How do I make it so that the user can open it in a new window or tab if they want (either through context-menu or shortcuts)?

Comment: If you want to open the new content in a new window - why are you using AJAX?

Comment: i mean, its for user to decide, if user wants to, then he/she can, but by default it will try to ajax and only return parts of the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide a valid href-attribute, users should be able to open the link in a new tab by selecting "Open in new tab" from the **context menu**.

To detect if a user clicked on the link while **holding down any "special key"** (e.g. alt, shift, "meta", this last one is the one you want I guess), use the click event's properties provided by jQuery: [see this example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7M889/) and the respective section in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). Hope it helps to catch the CMD-clicks commonly used to open a link in a new tab/window.

```
$("a").on("click",function(e){
    if(e.metaKey) {
        // the user probably wants to open the link in a new tab
    } else {
        // simple click, so do your AJAX call here
    }
});
```

Also, see this ["Key event properties" table](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_events.html#keyprops) for more information. Seems jQuery sets the metaKey property to `event.ctrlKey` if its undefined (search for "metaKey" in [jQuery's source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js)).

Answer (score -1):

add attribute target="_blank" in hyperlink. So, on click of the url, new window will be used.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">click here </a>
```